# Change data from modal sheet in flutter without changing the modal itself

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have 4 modal sheets in flutter, the order is modal-1 -> modal-2 -> modal-3 -> modal-4.

so, one modal goes down and other pops up ! is there any way in which I can stop this going down and poping up of another modal?

I'm using Bloc architecture on stateless widgets.

please help me to achieve any of the following, or suggest some thing else
1 - change data from instead of changing modal itself.
2 - stop modal going down and poping up animation.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples so we can best assist you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and used `IndexedStack` inside of the modal. So in essence, the actual content widgets (not the entire modal) from Sheet 1-4 become child widgets of the IndexedStack which actually is inside the modal.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ParentModalContent extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentModal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ParentModalContentState createState() => _ParentModalContentState();
}

class _ParentModalContentState extends State<ParentModalContent> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(
      children: [
        Child1(
          onNext: () {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
            });
          },
        ),
        // more widgets
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onNext;
  const Child1({Key? key, required this.onNext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        // content
        );
  }
}
```

Wrap the `ParentModalContent` inside of the function that shows your modal.